# How to Find Major and Minor Axis, and Non-Overlapping area of Contour using fitEllipse in OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv, contour

I am working on the image processing project in Android. I want to extract some features from extracted object. I am facing two problems in my project at this moment.

1. I want to calculate major and minor axis of the extracted area. After that I want to calculate the non-overlapping area of the extracted object. (I have tried using fitellipse method, but it returns only RotatedRect in android).
2. I want to use red (or any other) color to draw the shapes on final displayed image, but all the shapes are drawn in white color irrespective of the input color.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) "(I have tried using fitellipse method, but it returns only RotatedRect in android). "

And this is exactly what you want. The size-member contains the length of you major and minor axis.

2) And why don't you show some code?

Comment: Thanks, It helped for major and minor axis, what about the non overlapping area?